# How to get thead to the top on scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have problem creating sticky thead, my first 3 columns are fixed, rest of data is scrollable horizontal. I'm using jquery library for the sticky header, but position fixed is destroying my horizontal scroll, displaying all elements on the page. 
I need sticky header to stay at the top, and at the same time horizontal scroll to work.

[image: screenshot]

This is how it should look but with sticky header.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kH2RO.png)

```css
.horizontal-scroll-access-point {
  display: block;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  thead,tbody {
    tr {
      //First three elements are fixed
      th,td {
        &:nth-child(1), &:nth-child(2), &:nth-child(3){
          background-color: white;
          position:absolute;
          text-align: center;
          width: 100px;
          padding-bottom: 10px;
          z-index: 1;
        }
        &:nth-child(1) {
          left: 0;
        }
        &:nth-child(2) {
          left: 100px;
        }
        &:nth-child(3) {
          left: 180px;
        }
        &:nth-child(4) {
          padding-left: 300px;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
    <table class="table monthTable horizontal-scroll-access-point" ng-if="showActions()">
        <thead class="sticky-header" sticky-divs sticky-divs-margin-top="50">
            <tr>
                <th class="heading" translate>SH_Area</th>
                <th><span translate>AP_openClose</span></th>
                <th translate>AP_maxUnits</th>
                <th class="hour hover-cell" ng-repeat="hour in apu.hours" ng-click="changeUnitsAllByHourModal(hour)" on-finish-render>
                    <span ng-bind="hour | hourminute"></span>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="area in apu.areaHours">
                <td ng-class="area.closed ? 'closed-cell' : 'hover-cell'" ng-click="changeUnitsAllByAccessPointModal(area)"><strong ng-bind="area.accessPointName"></strong></td>
                <td class="open-close-cell">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" ng-class="area.closed ? 'btn-danger' : 'btn-success'" ng-click="switchAreaStatus(area)" translate>{{ area.closed ? 'AP_closed' : 'AP_opened' }}</button>
                </td>
                <td class="gradient-cell-green" ng-bind="area.maxUnits">
                </td>
                <td ng-class="area.closed ? 'closed-cell' : 'hover-cell'" style="background-color: rgba(110, 170, 120, {{ hour.units / area.maUnits }})" ng-repeat="hour in area.hours" ng-click="changeUnitsModal(area, hour)">
                    <span ng-bind="area.closed ? '0' : hour.units"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only change the position of `thead` and then give each one of the `th` elements the same width as the width of the widest `tr` element in that column.

I assume your table is responsive. If so, write some `js` code to do so.

Comment: I have tried that,  but I have a problem matching th and td vertical. The table is not responsive, it's scrollable. Position fixed is displaying all elements, so that horizontal scroll is not working

Comment: Could you add some of your data in your answer?